# SQL return value based on results of subset data

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'll try my best to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a table with the following subset of data:

```
ID    BF_ID    C_ID    T_ID
1     1        10000   182
2     1        230     null
3     2        123     null
4     3        10000   124
```

Basically I would like to query this table based on the `BF_ID` to see if there is data present that has BOTH a not null `T_ID` AND a not null C_ID in the results.

In the above example, I would like to distinguish  between querying between the different BF_IDs. NUmbers of rows for the BF_id could be infinite.

- BF_ID of 1 would return "mixed".
- BF_ID of 2 would return "C_ID_ATTRIB"
- BF_ID of 3 would return "T_ID_ATTRIB"

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why the `bf_id` of 1 is different from the `bf_id` of 3.  Both appear to have non-null data in both the `C_ID` and the `T_ID` columns.  But one should return "mixed" while the other should return "T_ID_ATTRIB".  What is the logic that allows you to differentiate those two?

Answer (score 1):

You just need a group by and case statement for this:

```
select bf_id,
       (case when count(t_id) = 0 and count(c_id) = 0 then 'Neither'
             when count(t_id) > 0 and count(c_id) = 0 then 'T_ID_ATTRIB'
             when count(t_id) = 0 and count(c_id) > 0 then 'C_ID_ATTRIB'
             else 'Mixed'
        end) as WhichAttribute
from t
group by bf_id
```

Comment: Cant find how to delete this comment...?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to example provided by Gordon, maybe more readable:
(just typed without test)

`select bf_id, 
  case when c is null and t is null
       then 'neither'
    when c is null and t is not null
       then 'T_ID_ATTRIB'
    when c is not null and t is null
       then 'C_ID_ATTRIB'
    else
     'mixed' as which_attr
from (
select bf_id, max(c_id) c, max(t_id) t
from
table1
group by bf_id)`